# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare(). Error en mi sitio web

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia!!!. Tengo un problema que no puedo resolver, hice un proyecto en php el cual ya funcionaba en localhost pero al pasarlo a un servidor me manda este error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare().Ya hice la base de datos en el servidor y sigue el problema. Les agradeceria muchisimo su ayuda.

```
function conexion($db, $usuario, $pass){
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=162.241.62.49;dbname=$db", $usuario, $pass);
        return $conexion;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

$conexion = conexion('armando2_admin_photoamc', 'victor', 'victorphotoamc');

$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT name_album FROM albums"); //Aquí me marca el error
$statement->execute();
$name = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es un error en los parametros de conexión, no hay error en tu código, verifica las credenciales de conexión.

A tu código de conexión agrega el [manejo de errores de PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.error-handling.php), solo le debes agregar `array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING)` como atributo al constructor de la clase PDO  y en el catch un echo para ver el error:

```html
function conexion($db, $usuario, $pass){
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=162.241.62.49;dbname=$db", $usuario, $pass, 
                             array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
        return $conexion;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage(); //Agrega un echo solo para ver el error de conexion
    }
}
```

Sin embargo te recomiendo que si estas trabajando orientado a objetos como lo es la libreria PDO no te salgas de esa linea, deberías crear una clase para hacer las consulta (Modelo) para cada  una de tus tablas y no una función como estas haciendo.

Un código de referencia:

```html
class Any
{
    private $conn;


    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function getTable($var)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE colum = $var LIMIT 1";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :D, espero que funcione!!!

Comment: Recuerda marcar la  respuesta que te ayudó a resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, verifique las credenciales de conexión y funciono.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya ayudado, recuerda marcar como correcta la respuesta por favor.

Comment: Listo amigo, muchas gracias y perdona por no hacerlo antes pero soy nuevo en la pagina y no sabia como hacerlo. saludos